# Use ssh from Windows command prompt

Tags: windows, ssh, cmd, scp

**Question:**
How to use ssh & scp from the Windows command prompt?

I remember I installed a program in the past that let me do this but can't remember now what it was.

**Note:**
I do not want to use putty.

Comment: PuTTY includes `pscp` and `plink`, which is for SCP and for SSH directly from a console window. Did you mean those, mayhaps? They are not necessarily noticeable as parts of PuTTY.

Comment: If you have git installed, there will be an ssh command available from git bash

Comment: `Git bash` and  `Cygwin` can help you with that.

Comment: You can enable linux subsystem on windows 10... then you can just type ssh.

Comment: It comes with Windows 10. c:\> ssh

Comment: There's a specific answer for Windows 10 here as well as other windows versions - https://stackoverflow.com/a/40720527/5362826

Answer (score 26, accepted):

New, resurrected project site (Win7 compability and more!): http://sshwindows.sourceforge.net

> **1st January 2012**
>
> - OpenSSH for Windows 5.6p1-2 based release created!!
> - Happy New Year all! Since COpSSH has started charging I've resurrected this project
> - Updated all binaries to current releases
> - Added several new supporting DLLs as required by all executables in package
> - Renamed switch.exe to bash.exe to remove the need to modify and compile mkpasswd.exe each build
> - Please note there is a very minor bug in this release, detailed in the docs. I'm working on fixing this, anyone who can code in C and can offer a bit of help it would be much appreciated

Comment: The linked website does not work: Error code: ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Comment: The link is still broken (1 year after @burzum's comment).

Comment: Even though the site now works again - the download files it takes you to, suggests that it is still the 2004 version. However there is a page on the main OpenSSH site with Windows installers: http://www.mls-software.com/opensshd.html

Comment: Don't use the software linked to in the answer. It removes your entire system path variable.

Comment: This is working for me in Windows 7, but wiped my path like others mentioned (I backed up after reading comments here and on the site)

Answer (score 15):

Cygwin can give you this functionality.

Comment: Seems like a better way to go since you get a lot of other unix stuff too.

Answer (score 7):

Try [WinScp](http://winscp.net)

Comment: WinSCP scripting reference: http://winscp.net/eng/docs/scripting; or a guide to a scripting: http://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_automation

Answer (score 0):

Give http://www.privateshell.com/ a shot.