# "ssh-add" is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssh, addition

using ruby on rails command prompt I am trying to add my generated public key to the authentication agent by using the following command

```
"ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa"
```

and the return message I get

```
"ssh-add is not recognized as an internal or external command"
```

Is there another way to write this and get the same result?

Answer (score 1):

`XYZ is not recognized as an internal or external command` is part of the error message on windows machine that is telling that the specified command was not found for various reasons.

The full error message would be:

> XYZ is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Either ssh-add is not installed in the system, or it is added but not in the path.

The following could be helpful:

- [How to run ssh-add on windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18683092/how-to-run-ssh-add-on-windows)
- [How to fix “not recognized as an internal or external command” in Windows](http://helpdeskgeek.com/how-to/fix-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command/)