# cmake not able to read ssh keys when it calls 'git' command

Tags: windows, git, cmake

I would like to let 'cmake' exporting some files from a git repository with a 'git export' command. Everytime I do that I received an error

```
Permission denied, please try again.
git@xxxx: Permission denied (publickey,password).
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

If I do it myself from a DOS command line I am asked a password in a prompt.
As far as I know my ssh keys have been already provided to the network administrator watching for the git repositories.

Do you know why  'cmake' is not able to pick up my ssh keys?
How to prevent asking the password for it?

Below the command I am using

```
execute_process(
    COMMAND git --remote=git+ssh://git@xx/proj.git master source/folder --format=tar.gz  > package.tar.gz
    RESULT_VARIABLE rv
    ERROR_VARIABLE  ev
    OUTPUT_VARIABLE ov
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think CMake cannot ask for user input, so when invoking the Git command and it asks for a password then the input is empty, which causes your command to fail.

You should use a SSH agent so that SSH is already "aware" of your SSH keys so your Git command does not ask for a password; for example [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18683544/948128) indicates how to use it. Another solution would be to pass your password through an environment variable, but the first solution is more appropriate in my opinion.

Comment: What about a credential helper for git?

Comment: Hi Christoph!Thanks a lot. it helps as well.