# Fetch, pull, merge or push a change to GitHub gitbash gives {git: 'credential-cache' is not a git command. See 'git -- help'.}

Tags: windows, git, github, credential-manager, credentialscache

This error

> git: 'credential-cache' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.

is showing every time I try to interact with GitHub:
[image: this error({git: 'credential-cache' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.}) is showing everytime i try to interact with github]

In order to get out of the pain of typing my GitHub idname & password each time I fetch, pull, merge and push changes to the GitHub, I thought of using the
`git config --global credential.helper cache` command to store the idname & password. After using it I learned that, as I'm using Windows, I had to use `manager` instead of `cache` to do the same task. However, the above error message is showing each time I try to interact with GitHub.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have never used a credential helper. But, I think it would require you to install a third-party tool to get it working.

- `refer to` https://stackoverflow.com/a/5343146/7409008
- `check` https://github.com/microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows

---

As a recommendation, I would tell you to use ssh keys [`cite^`](https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise/2.15/user/articles/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account) instead of a third-party tool, you are more secure this way. Even more secure if you use a passphrase along with ssh-agent [`cite^`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18683092/how-to-run-ssh-add-on-windows).