# Sharing ssh credentials with dev container in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, ssh-keys, vscode-devcontainer, git-credential-manager

I have setup a VS Code dev container and I can run and debug my code inside. My `~/.gitconfig` from my host system was correctly copied into the container. However, my ssh credentials don't seem to work (or are not available), neither are my gnupg signing files (`~/.gnupg`) available.

Must I manually copy these files ( `~/.ssh` and `~/.gnupg`) into the container?

The [documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/remote/advancedcontainers/sharing-git-credentials#_using-ssh-keys) cautions:

> There are some cases when you may be cloning your repository using SSH keys instead of a credential helper. To enable this scenario, the extension will automatically forward your local SSH agent if one is running.

The only stated requirement is the SSH-agent server running on my host system, which it is:

```
C:\Windows\system32> Get-Service ssh-agent

Status   Name               DisplayName
------   ----               -----------
Running  ssh-agent          OpenSSH Authentication Agent
```

What is the correct way to make my SSH credentials available to my dev container?

Comment: Could you share your container config and any relevant settings in your `.gitconfig`? I'm having difficulty reproducing.

Comment: Since it works on your machine, I gave it a try on another and it works there as well. I think I found the culprit, the `.ssh` folder was set to another path and hence the mounting of `.ssh` pointed to the wrong folder. Feel free to post your example `.devcontainer.json` and I staple my bounty to it. Don't want the points being lost, so better they serve someone who tried checking out this question.

Comment: So I updated my answer this morning, I think maybe the issue is you have terminal.integrated.inheritEnv unchecked? See my answer.

Comment: That was it, I overwrote it in my local project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple prerequisites.

1. You must have VS Code setting `terminal.integrated.inheritEnv` enabled.
2. You must have your ssh-agent ran at login.

VS Code supports your ssh settings via doing two things:

- Copying in `known_hosts` from your `~/.ssh/known_hosts`.
- Finding your ssh-agent socket created when you logged into the system.

For me on macOS, the `ssh-agent` creates a file in a random location, e.g.:

```
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/vscode-ssh-auth-1a6abf46-1c35-41bf-aedd-e08135a38f5f.sock
```

My login scripts performs two commands, in this example I ran them on the command line:

```
% eval `ssh-agent`
Agent pid 15376

% ssh-add
Identity added: /Users/risner/.ssh/id_rsa (/Users/risner/.ssh/id_rsa)
```

For Windows, this answer should help in setting up the agent:
[How to run ssh-add on windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18683544)

Once created, all your containers should pick it up without specific settings. Here is a test `.devcontainer.json` file:

```
{
  "build": {
    "dockerfile": "Dockerfile",
    "args": { "VARIANT": "hirsute" }
  },
  "forwardPorts": [3000]
}
```

For a M1 Mac, the `hirsute` variant picks up the native arm64.

My test `Dockerfile` is rather generic:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/devcontainers/javascript-node:0-18
RUN apt-get update && export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive \
    && apt-get -y install git
```

Once in the container, I verified the keys worked:

```
node ➜ /workspaces/MySSH (master) $ set|grep -i ssh
PWD=/workspaces/MySSH
REMOTE_CONTAINERS_SOCKETS='["/tmp/vscode-ssh-auth-1a6abf46-1c35-41bf-aedd-e08135a38f5f.sock","/tmp/.X11-unix/X0"]'
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/vscode-ssh-auth-1a6abf46-1c35-41bf-aedd-e08135a38f5f.sock
node ➜ /workspaces/MySSH (master) $ ssh risner@my.example.com
Last login: Mon Mar  6 08:31:03 2023 from 172.59.80.11
```

Comment: The official docs indicate that ssh agent forwarding should work by default on macOS however they _do not_ mention that setting `terminal.integrated.inheritEnv` is required. This answer is the only place I've seen it mentioned in many hours of troubleshooting. Edit: I forgot to mention - the answer is correct and this is incredibly helpful, thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

It is also possible to achieve this with the mount capability of the `devcontainer.json` configuration file:

```json
    {
        "name": "container name",
        ...
        "remoteUser": "root",  
        "mounts": [
            "source=${localEnv:HOME}/.ssh,target=/root/.ssh,type=bind,consistency=cached",
        ]
       ...
    }
```

Comment: That's neat, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

With my version of dev containers there is a folder

```
/home/vscode
```

The correct mount option is therefore

```
"mounts": [
    "source=${localEnv:HOME}/.ssh,target=/home/vscode/.ssh,type=bind,consistency=cached",
]
```

extra info:
I needed this, since I have two github accounts with two ssh keys. When only the ssh agent is forwarded, git is picking up the wrong ssh key and authentication fails.

To solve this I added two hosts in the .ssh/config.

```
Host git_priv
  Hostname github.com
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_git_private
  IdentitiesOnly yes

Host github.com
  Hostname github.com
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
  IdentitiesOnly yes
```

Basically I set one ssh key as standard (using github.com as the host) and the the other to only work with github-private.com as domain. If I now inlclude this git config with the above command into the devcontainer, I get the correct ssh key resolution.