# How to use SSH credentials and GPG for dev container in vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger, vscode-devcontainer, git-credential-manager

I am using VScode on macOS and are exploring dev containers to use for development to encapsulate all dependencies required to build my Go project. I created a dev container from my existing local Git repository and installed Ubuntu with Python and Go dependencies.

If I understand correctly, but local Git repository will be obsolete and my entire project will be moved into a container. How do I setup Git in that case? it is installed but doesn't have access to my local `~/.ssh` or `~/.gnupg` directory.

The VScode documentation has a page called [Sharing Git credentials with your container](https://code.visualstudio.com/remote/advancedcontainers/sharing-git-credentials) and states it should work out of the box:

> The Dev Containers extension provides out of the box support for using local Git credentials from inside a container. In this section, we'll walk through the two supported options.

My local `.gitconfig` has set `user`, `email` and `signingkey`. Still a push and pull within the container leads to:

> git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
>
> fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights
> and the repository exists.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

I discovered via [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75829669) that the setting `terminal.integrated.inheritEnv` must be set to `true` for the agent forwarding to work correctly.

Without this setting the `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` environment variable is not set in the devcontainer. After enabling Inherit Env and reopening the project in the devcontainer `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` should look something like: `/tmp/vscode-ssh-auth-7c68defd-3baf-4a17-83e0-b4bc9d31eb12.sock`